# mongodump 3.4.1 error reading collection: Closed explicitly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodump

[BACKUP COMMAND]: mongodump -u `username` -p `password` -d `database` --port `port` -o `output path`.

[ISSUE]: error writing data for collection to disk: error reading collection: Closed explicitly.

The storage requirements of my MongoDB database are constantly increasing. So far the database is using 20 GB of disk space and I am encountering errors when I want to dump the database. It always fails and the above issue is displayed in the terminal shell when I use the above `mongodump` command. I have to reissue the `mongodump` command again and again until the backup of the database finishes.

So my questions are:

- Is there a good alternative database backup tool/command for MongoDB?
- Is there a stable and fast backup command for large-scale MongoDB databases?
- Am I using the correct procedure?

Comment: I feel your pain.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Could you add a question and possibly reword your question? It is hard to understand what your problem is and what issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: yeah, I have reworded my question.  and now I' m not sure it is easy-understand for you?

Comment: Based on your recent edit, I have tried to reword your question to increase readability. I hope you agree. If you have any objections, please visit the [question's revisions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/206996/revisions) and rollback to your version.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. by the way, are you an administrator of this website?

Comment: There have been many bug fixes & improvements since MongoDB 3.4.1 was released. Can you try with the latest 3.4.x version of `mongodump` (currently 3.4.15)? If that doesn't resolve the issue, can you please confirm: what type of deployment you have (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster), your specific O/S version, and your `mongodump` command line. For alternative backup approaches, see [Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups) in the MongoDB manual. For larger or more complex deployments, typical backup approaches are to use backup agents or filesystem snapshots.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I have a question, I don't know whether it would affect the functionality of the previous database or not when I update mongo version. I have replica set deployment on my machines, and O/S version is Ubuntu16.04, and my backup command is ` mongodump -u username -p password -d database --port port -o output path`.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from the horse's mouth (ie. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-mongodump):

> mongodump and mongorestore are simple and efficient tools for backing up
>   and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal
>   for capturing backups of larger systems.

Comment: thank you, do you have an ideal backup command for larger systems in mongo

Comment: I don't, but see Markus's answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/how-to-backup-large-mongodb-database.  Are you currently running without backup???  Better hurry to put that right and do not forget to test your recovery scenario.

Comment: so far I use 'mongodump' command to back up database, but I haven't tested the recovery scenario.

Comment: So, the mongodump succeeds after a number of tries? Please add the exact syntax of your command to your question.

Comment: Exactly. Yes, the mongodump would be successful after a number of tries. Sorry I don't understand what you say "Please add the exact syntax of your command to your question", do you mean what I describe is not specific or you want to know the specific backup command what I use

Comment: The specific command.

Comment: ok, I have added it

Comment: Is your DB being written to during the backup?

Comment: yeah, you're right. this DB is for online service, so I didn't shut up online service when I back up.

Comment: Unless you can put the service in some "read only" mode for the duration of the backup, you should read about the "oplog" option of mongodump.  How did the recovery test turn out?